# no entries or files visible

Tags: craft3, entries, redirect

I got given a db dump using Craft 3.5.16. After installing all the dependencies using composer and npm  I can login to the admin section.

However, I do not see any entries or any files in the admin section. In the frontend, I can only see the basic skeleton of the website including the footer and the correct CSS but no content. All links in the footer redirect to the live website though they should go to local pages.

The `DEFAULT_SITE_URL` is set in .env, pointing to the right local URL. There are no errors in the logs either.

Any clue what could be going on would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: Stupid question: I assume they also gave you the credentials to log into the CP and have administrator access? If you can log into the live site, that would be helpful to compare. You're also going to need the site's ``templates`` folder to replicate the live site.

Comment: yeah i can log into the live site and can compare stuff but i got no idea anymore where to look. locally, i can also log into the admin section but i see none of the content. when i browse the database the content is there though.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong on this but...

After running composer, did you have to go through an install process? If so, the DB/site you were given might have been configured to use a database table prefix.

If you look in your database, do you see some tables call `assets` then a second one called `xxx_assets` (`xxx_` could be anything)?

If so, in your `.env` file, make sure have `DB_TABLE_PREFIX=` set to whatever prefix (the `xxx_` part) you are seeing on your tables.

Comment: yeah they use a prefix and i've set it in .env so this is not the problem :(

Comment: Argh... Worth a shot :) Do you see rows in your `entries` or `assets` table?

Comment: jup, plenty of stuff in both of them :(

Comment: Do you know if the account you are login in with an admin account?

Comment: yeah it is an admin account

Comment: Send your `composer.json`, `composer.lock` and a database backup to support@craftcms.com and we'll help you from there